# Php dynamic class construction

Tags: php

I'm trying to avoid the use of `eval`. I can dynamically instantiate a class like this:

```
class myclass {}

$my_class_name = 'myclass';
$obj = new $myclass();
```

If the constructor is like follows:

```
class myclass {
    public function __construct( $argument1, $argument2 ) {}
}
```

and i have the values of the arguments in an array, how can i dynamically instantiate the class **and** pass it dynamic arguments? Mind that I have no way to modify the class, so I have to work on the way of using it.

Thanks

Comment: is it useful:
$argList = array(...);
$obj = new $$myclass($arglist)

Comment: i tried this, but it passes an array as argument, not its items as arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) seems to be just the thing you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
$obj = new $myclass($array['key1'], $Arr['key2'], ...);
```