# PHP: How to create class by its name?

Tags: php, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php dynamic class construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826711/php-dynamic-class-construction)

How i can create an object from class by its name?

Like this

```
$name = "test";
$test = "text from var";
print ${$name};
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
class SomeClass {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "construct SomeClass";
    }
}

$className = 'SomeClass';
$obj = new $className();
```

Output: `construct SomeClass`

Comment: @ohmusama Not necessary: http://viper-7.com/VpWQnR

Comment: @ohmusama just for you, I edited

Comment: viper7 is very powerful! tnx!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're asking for....

```
$classname = "MyClassName";
$newObject = new $className();
```

However, I would recommend avoiding dynamic class names (or indeed, any variable variables as per your question), because it can make debugging much much harder, and also you lose all the help that a good IDE can give you such as intellisense.

Comment: Dynamic class/function/variable names are one of the strengths of PHP, though.  Recommending not to use it just because IDEs don't play well with it doesn't seem right to me. :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn - it's one of the features of PHP. I don't think it's one of the strengths. I've seen it used a *lot*, but I've never ever seen it used in a way that couldn't have been done without using it. Most of the time I've seen it used it's outright bad code. It's not as bad a `eval()`, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's a better way of instantiating a class that isn't known until runtime?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking to do this. Maybe?

```
$myObject = new $name();
```